# Programmatically downloading multiple emails from outlook

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api, office365-apps

I wish to programmatically download multiple emails from Outlook mailbox (in msg format).
I have few options but neither provides a complete solution.

Option 1:

Using Microsoft Graph I can retrieve emails from users inbox, but API provides no methods for downloading. I'd have to use something like MSG .NET library (which is not free) to build msg files by hand.

Option 2:

Using 
Office.js I can retrieve only opened email. There is no access to other emails in the same inbox. This requires JS code to run in add-in but I'm ok with that.

Is there any other options? I know request is kind of unorthodox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a way to get MSG format from Microsoft Graph. You'd have to construct MSG files from the data you get for the Microsoft Graph API. You can either use the solution from IndependentSoft, or here's another option:

Option 3: Create your own MSG file [using the spec](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc463912(v=EXCHG.80).aspx).

Can you tell us why the MSG file format is a requirement for your solution?  Perhaps there are other options based on your answer.

Comment: I'd like to automate saving of emails from outlook to external storage (sharepoint/one drive/dropbox) for archiving. Msg format is required for ease of use as its native to Outlook and you can just open it up, respond, etc.

Comment: Just so I'm clear, is this from consumer accounts like outlook.com and hotmail.com, or for business accounts? What type of application is this (line of business, something you're selling to enterprises)?

How hard is your requirement for external storage and ability to 'just open it up'?

I ask as Exchange Online has an archive mailbox option that can be used to automatically archive emails, and allows easy access from Outlook.

Comment: Its for business accounts. Basically we'd like to manage archiving fully in our app, so that users don't need to setup anything. User's would chose from which emails to archive, so its not automatic archiving of all emails.
Ideally I'd just want to be able to drag and drop emails to external storage (like SharePoint) however outlook doesn't support it (no HTML5 FileAPI support) and this is approach we decided is the best alternative.

Comment: I'm unaware of an optimal solution for your requirements of external storage, 'just opens up, respond'. For just full fidelity external storage of an archive, use the EWS API with the ExportItems and UploadItems API. For the 'just opens up' requirement, you can easily create a .eml file that will just open up in Outlook. Although this is not a full fidelity archive. For the 'respond' requirement, you'd need to use the UploadItems API to put it back in the mailbox before responding (I think). Perhaps your solution could use stubs to represent a full-fidelity archive.

Comment: If I can get eml file from EWS API easily that could work! Thank you for your help, I'll accept the answer as it answers my question after these comments. I'll try the EWS approach.